# Insert Data in a table but not linked whit table

Tags: php, mysql

What i want to do is to insert a data in my column "Score" but not from a row cuz not included in my phpmyadmin table.

Actually this data is an addtion of 5 previous column, and i make the addition whit a query mysql.

Here is my table :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
<?php
    // Include config file
    require_once 'configgate.php';
$bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cmadatabase','root','@Rugby3390');
$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$reponse= $bdd->query('SELECT `ID`,`Level`,`Typ`,`Occurrence`,`Supplier`,`Consequences`,
                                SUM((/*0.5**/`Level`)+/*0.5**/`Typ`+/*0.5**/`Occurrence`+/*0.5**/`Supplier`+/*0.5**/`Consequences`) AS sommeLTOSC 
                        FROM `andgate` 
                        GROUP BY `ID`,`Level`,`Typ`,`Occurrence`,`Supplier`,`Consequences` 
                        ORDER BY sommeLTOSC  DESC');
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()){

    //echo $donnees['sommeLTOSC'].'<p>';
}
                // Attempt select query execution
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM andgate";
                if($result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
                    if($result->num_rows > 0){
                        echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                            echo "<thead>";
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<th>ID</th>";
                                    echo "<th>IR</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Level</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Type</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Occurrence</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Supplier</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Consequences</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Candidate TBA</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Engineer Judgment</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Remarks</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Score</th>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            echo "</thead>";
                            echo "<tbody>";
                            while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['IR'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['Level'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['Typ'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['Occurrence'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['Supplier'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['Consequences'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['Candidate'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['Engineer'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['Remarks'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $donnees['sommeLTOSC'] . "</td>";
```

My problem is whit the echo at the end, i can t access the data, could you help me ?
Thanks a lot

Here is my code revised :

```
 <?php
                    // Include config file
                   require_once 'configgate.php';


    $reponse= $mysqli->query("SELECT `ID`,`Level`,`Typ`,`Occurrence`,`Supplier`,`Consequences`,
                                    SUM((/*0.5**/`Level`)+/*0.5**/`Typ`+/*0.5**/`Occurrence`+/*0.5**/`Supplier`+/*0.5**/`Consequences`) AS sommeLTOSC 
                            FROM `andgate` 
                            GROUP BY `ID`,`Level`,`Typ`,`Occurrence`,`Supplier`,`Consequences` 
                            ORDER BY sommeLTOSC  DESC");
    while ($row = $reponse->fetch())





                    // Attempt select query execution
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM andgate";
                    if($result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
                        if($result->num_rows > 0){
                            echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                                echo "<thead>";
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<th>ID</th>";
                                        echo "<th>IR</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Level</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Type</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Occurrence</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Supplier</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Consequences</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Candidate TBA</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Engineer Judgment</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Remarks</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Score</th>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                echo "</thead>";
                                echo "<tbody>";
                                while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['IR'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['Level'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['Typ'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['Occurrence'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['Supplier'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['Consequences'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['Candidate'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['Engineer'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['Remarks'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['sommeLTOSC'] . "</td>";
```

Here is my error : Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch() in C:\wamp64\www\&Gate\indexgate.php on line 49

Thx

Comment: you're mixing different mysql apis; you can't do that.

Comment: and your connection/query variables don't match

Comment: OK, thanks so could you help me ?

Comment: use the same api from connecting to querying. Either PDO or mysqli, and not `and`. Consult the manuals http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: OK, so i am having a go

Comment: Could you guide me once more ? i edited my code but ...

Comment: you overwrote your question completely. You should have kept the original one intact and added the new code *under* it and marked as as additional edit. You also need to check for errors and include them in the edit.

Comment: I rolled the question back to a previous revision.

Comment: OK, get it sry i am new